# Reset form values onload in bootsfaces

Tags: java, reset, bootsfaces

I need to reset the form fields and clear the form values onload.
However I used -

```
    public void refresh() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    ViewHandler viewHandler = application.getViewHandler();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, context
     .getViewRoot().getViewId());
    context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
    context.renderResponse(); //Optional
   }
```

The above code is working but when I am entering values in fields using  in panelgroup , its not working.

```
<h:panelGroup>
<ui:repeat value="#{formDynAttrbBean.vals}" var="values">
    <b:panelGrid columns="6" cellspacing="4">
        <b:inputText id="label" value="">
        </b:inputText>
        <b:selectOneMenu value="">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="SelectType" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="" />
        </b:selectOneMenu>
        <b:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" />
        <b:commandButton actionListener="#{form.types}" />
    </b:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
<b:commandButton tooltip="Add new attribute" tooltip-position="bottom"
    iconAwesome="plus" actionListener="#{form.add}" update="@form" />
<tr />
<b:commandButton value="Save" ajax="true"
    actionListener="#{form.submit}" update="@form" />
<tr />
<b:commandButton type="reset" action="#{formController.refresh}"
    value="Reset">
</b:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Refresh function is not working in this case when I am entering values in panelgroup and in repeating fields.**
I am just a beginner to bootsfaces.Please suggest me an approach.Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to clear the input fields of the form. For example, JSF 2.2 has the `resetValues="true"` attribute (see [the article of Michael Kurz](https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/jsf-22-reset-values/) (probably not implemented by BootsFaces). Another option is to use `<b:commandButton type="reset">`.

But I wonder why you want to reset the values on the client side? You have to clear them because they display some "dirty" (i.e. modified) backend bean. IMHO the better approach is to create a new, empty backend bean.

Comment: Thankyou.... But Could you please explain programmatically how to empty values in bean on Reset?

Comment: You've already got a `refresh` method, right? I'd simply set every attribute of the bean manually to null, or to a new instance of the object if the attribute is not a primitive data type. BTW, using this approach, you have to remove the `type="reset"` bit. It prevents the bean method from being called.